# Ubuntu 16.0.4 - How to run PHP 5 in a specific directory

Tags: linux, ubuntu, php

I have a VPS running ubuntu 16.0.4. I have already installed the lamp stack. I have an application I bought from code canyon which needs PHP 5.6 to run.

```
Main App (directory)
--------
  code-canyon-app (this directory needs PHP 5)
```

How can I install PHP 5 and make it available to the app directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can have different php installed in ubuntu and config the for your app
Install your php version with apt-get and refer them to your apache or app you need to use https://devanswers.co/run-multiple-php-versions-on-apache/

Comment: Do I have to uninstall PHP 7.0 I have already installed?

Comment: No Need just follow guide and Use it in your app , if you want one of them as default put them in environment variable or use it in lamp stack